# Better coding practice when using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, for-loop

I am trying to improve my coding practices when writing functions. My final goal is to get the amount of time it took to accomplish a type of task on a specific team. I have a starting dataframe with the code:

```
    data = {'Team':['A', 'A', 'A', 'B','B','B','A','B'], 'Time':[20, 21, 19, 18,17,15,22,25],'Type':['Bike', 'Car', 'Walk', 'Scooter','Bike', 'Car', 'Walk', 'Scooter']} 

   df_new = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I then write a function like:

```
def timer(df):
    team_A = df[df['Team'] == 'A']
    team_A_time_total = team_A.Time.sum()

    team_A_biketime_ = (team_A[team_A['Type'] == 'Bike'].Time.sum() / team_A_time_total)
    team_A_cartime_ = (team_A[team_A['Type'] == 'Car'].Time.sum() / team_A_time_total)
    team_A_walktime_ = (team_A[team_A['Type'] == 'Walk'].Time.sum() / team_A_time_total)
    team_A_scootertime_ = (team_A[team_A['Type'] == 'Scooter'].Time.sum() / team_A_time_total)

    team_B = df[df['Team'] == 'B']
    team_B_time_total = team_A.Time.sum()

    team_B_biketime_ = (team_B[team_B['Type'] == 'Bike'].Time.sum() / team_A_time_total)
    team_B_cartime_ = (team_B[team_B['Type'] == 'Car'].Time.sum() / team_A_time_total)
    team_B_walktime_ = (team_B[team_B['Type'] == 'Walk'].Time.sum() / team_A_time_total)
    team_B_scootertime_ = (team_B[team_B['Type'] == 'Scooter'].Time.sum() / team_A_time_total)

    return team_A_biketime_,team_A_cartime_, team_A_walktime_, team_A_scootertime_,team_B_biketime_,team_B_cartime_, team_B_walktime_, team_B_scootertime_
```

I know this code can be written in a more clean fashion but am having difficulty getting it correct. I have attempted:

```
def timer(df):
    types = ['Bike','Car','Walk','Scooter']
    teams = ['A','B']

    for team in teams: 
        df_team = df[df['Team'] == team]
        df_team_time = df_team.Time.sum()
        for value in types:
            df_value = df_team[df_team['Type'] == value]
            df_value_time = df_value.Time.sum() / df_team_time
    return df_value_time
```

This does not seem correct to me.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of better practice in pandas, it looks like you need to learn more about [`df.loc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

I think this is what you want:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Team':['A', 'A', 'A', 'B','B','B','A','B'], 'Time':[20, 21, 19, 18,17,15,22,25],'Type':['Bike', 'Car', 'Walk', 'Scooter','Bike', 'Car', 'Walk', 'Scooter']} 

df_new = pd.DataFrame(data) 

def timer(df, team, type):

    return df.loc[df['Team']==team].loc[df['Type']==type]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are writing a function to do something that pandas already does in an optimized manner. So, wherever possible, you should try to use `groupby` with aggregate functions.

So, for simple aggregates, you would use

```
df_new.groupby(['Team', 'Type'])['Time'].agg(['sum', 'mean'])
```

which produces this output

```
              sum  mean
Team Type              
A    Bike      20  20.0
     Car       21  21.0
     Walk      41  20.5
B    Bike      17  17.0
     Car       15  15.0
     Scooter   43  21.5
```

Once you are familiar with the basics, you can do more complex operations

```
summdf = df_new.groupby(['Team', 'Type'])['Time'].agg(['sum'])
summdf = summdf.reset_index()
summdf = summdf.rename(columns={'sum': 'team_type_sum'})
summdf['team_tot'] = summdf.groupby('Team')['team_type_sum'].transform('sum')
summdf['team_type_pct'] = summdf['team_type_sum'] / summdf['team_tot']
```

which produces

```
  Team     Type  team_type_sum  team_tot  team_type_pct
0    A     Bike             20        82       0.243902
1    A      Car             21        82       0.256098
2    A     Walk             41        82       0.500000
3    B     Bike             17        75       0.226667
4    B      Car             15        75       0.200000
5    B  Scooter             43        75       0.573333
```